# Floating new elements to the left of an existing element in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an input field that is floated left inside a form element. When the user presses , (comma), a tag is created. I would like each tag to appear to the left of the input field. However, even though I am floating them to the left, the tags that appear after a comma is pressed appear to the right of the input field.

How can I ensure that the tags are added to the left of the input field? Is it possible to change the order of the input element so that it's as if it was added after the tags?

Comment: provide simplified code

Comment: It sounds as though you are appending them after the input element. Floating them left wont put them to the left of the input element in that case. You need to append them before the input element. You need to show us the basic HTML structure and the Javascript you are using to create the new elements. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks @AHaworth, I worked around this by removing the input element before adding the tags, and then re-adding the input element after adding the tags and then focus()ing on the input element again. It's a hacky fix, but it happens so fast the user doesn't know. I'll come up with something better later.

Answer (score 2):

Floating them to left would not work in this situation.

You can cover it into a parent *div* and using **display:flex** on it and reversing its direction, so the new elements would go on the left instead of the right.

```
.parent{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, yet. But I will. I will accept this anwser soon. Thanks for helping.